# Can't reach item detail from API

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I'm doing an app using the API: https://gadhagod.github.io/Hyrule-Compendium-API/#/. Everything works fine until I try to paint item detail when clicking on item from a list. I'm not handling the way I try to access the properties of an item well, but I don't know where exactly I'm going wrong. I'm going to leave the navigation flow in detail but I don't know If it is to much content for asking

**CompendiumApi**

```
interface CompendiumApi {

    @GET("all?game=2")
    suspend fun getTearsAllEntries(): CompendiumList

    @GET("all?game=1")
    suspend fun getBreathAllEntries(): CompendiumList

    @GET("entry/{id}")
    suspend fun getItemInfo(
        @Path("id") id: Int
    ): Data
}
```

**CompendiumRepository**

```
@ActivityScoped
class CompendiumRepository @Inject constructor(
   private val api: CompendiumApi
){
   suspend fun getTearsAllEntries(): Resource<CompendiumList> {
      val response = try {
         api.getTearsAllEntries()
      } catch (e: Exception) {
         return Resource.Error("An unknown error occurred.")
      }
      return Resource.Success(response)
   }

   suspend fun getBreathAllEntries(): Resource<CompendiumList> {
      val response = try {
         api.getBreathAllEntries()
      } catch (e: Exception) {
         return Resource.Error("An unknown error occurred.")
      }
      return Resource.Success(response)
   }

   suspend fun getItemInfo(id: Int) : Resource<Data> {
      val response = try {
         Log.d("getItemInfo",api.getItemInfo(id).toString())
         api.getItemInfo(id)
      } catch (e: Exception) {
         return Resource.Error("An unknow error ocurred.")
      }
      return Resource.Success(response)
   }
}
```

**CompendiumDetailViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class CompendiumDetailViewModel @Inject constructor(
   private val repository: CompendiumRepository
) : ViewModel() {

   suspend fun getItemInfo(id: Int): Resource<Data> {
      return repository.getItemInfo(id)
   }
}
```

**CompendiumDetailScreen**

```
@Composable
fun CompendiumDetailCard(
   id: Int,
   viewModel: CompendiumDetailViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
   val itemInfo = produceState<Resource<Data>>(initialValue = Resource.Loading()) {
      value = viewModel.getItemInfo(id)
   }.value
   Log.d("itemDetailScreen", "item clicked: ${itemInfo.data.toString()}")
   ElevatedCard(
      elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
         defaultElevation = 6.dp
      ),
      modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxWidth()
   ) {
      ItemDetailStateWrapper(
         itemInfo = itemInfo,
         loadingModifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            .padding(
               top = 16.dp,
               start = 16.dp,
               end = 16.dp,
               bottom = 16.dp
            )
      )
   }
}

@Composable
fun ItemDetailStateWrapper(
   itemInfo: Resource<Data>,
   loadingModifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
   when(itemInfo){
      is Resource.Success -> {
         ItemDetailInfo(
            itemInfo = itemInfo.data!!
         )
      }
      is Resource.Error -> {
         Text(
            text = itemInfo.message!!,
            color = Color.Red,
         )
      }
      is Resource.Loading -> {
         CircularProgressIndicator(
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            modifier = loadingModifier
         )
      }
   }
}

@Composable
fun ItemDetailInfo(
   itemInfo: Data
){
   Text(text = itemInfo.name ?: "No name") //"No name painted"
}
```

**MainActivity using for navigate**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      window.statusBarColor = getColor(R.color.black)
      setContent {
         ZeldaCompendiumTheme {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(
               navController = navController,
               startDestination = "compendium_navigation"
            ) {
               composable("compendium_navigation") {
                  HomeContainer(navController = navController)
               }
               composable("compendium_tears_screen") {
                  TearsContainer(
                     navController = navController
                  )
               }
               composable("compendium_breath_screen") {
                  BreathContainer(
                     navController = navController
                  )
               }
               composable(
                  "item_detail_screen/{id}",
                  arguments = listOf(
                     navArgument("id") {
                        type = NavType.IntType
                     }
                  )
               ) {
                  val id = remember {
                     it.arguments?.getInt("id")
                  }
                  if (id != null) {
                     CompendiumDetailCard(
                        id = id,
                     )
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**CompendiumList**

```
data class CompendiumList(
   val data: List<Data>
)
```

**CompendiumListEntry**

```
data class CompendiumListEntry (
   val compendiumName: String,
   val category: String,
   val imageURL: String,
   val id: Int
)
```

**Data**

```
data class Data(
   val category: String,
   @SerializedName("common_location") val commonLocations: List<String>,
   @SerializedName("cooking_effect") val cookingEffect: String,
   val description: String,
   val dlc: Boolean,
   val drops: List<String>,
   val edible: Boolean,
   @SerializedName("fuse_attack_power") val fuseAttackPower: Int,
   @SerializedName("hearts_recovered")val heartsRecovered: Double,
   val id: Int,
   val image: String,
   val name: String,
   val properties: Properties
)
```

I must say that through the console I am painting the requests that are made when I interact with the screen, and when clicking on an item, the correct URL of the selected item is painted through the console:

[image]

Comment: So what happpens currently when you click the detail item? Does it just do nothing? You can try to use the debugger or add more log statements to see what is happening where.

Comment: @BenjyTec thanks for comment. I just updated with an image of the LogCat at the moment I click on an item

Comment: What is the log output for this code line in your ViewModel? `Log.d("getItemInfo",api.getItemInfo(id).toString())`

Comment: Please also include the `Data` class in your post.

Comment: Updated with data classes. That Log's output is the same as item clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there just is a simple mismatch between the JSON structure returned by the API and the data class structure that you want to parse the JSON into.

You will need to introduce a new data class or update your `CompendiumListItem` class as follows:

```
data class CompendiumListEntry (
   val data: Data
)
```

Then set this data class as the type of your `getItemInfo` API function:

```
@GET("entry/{id}")
suspend fun getItemInfo(
    @Path("id") id: Int
): CompendiumListEntry
```

Update all your calls to that function accordingly:

```
suspend fun getItemInfo(id: Int) : Resource<CompendiumListEntry> {
    val response = try {
       Log.d("getItemInfo",api.getItemInfo(id).data.toString())
       api.getItemInfo(id)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
       return Resource.Error("An unknow error ocurred.")
    }
    return Resource.Success(response)
}
```

And in your Composable, you will probably have to do this (I don't know how your Resource class is implemented):

```
val itemInfo = produceState<Resource<Data>>(initialValue = Resource.Loading()) {
    value = viewModel.getItemInfo(id)
}.value
Log.d("itemDetailScreen", "item clicked: ${itemInfo.data.data.toString()}")
```

Comment: You make my day! As you say, I've create a new data class and now works! I have been programming on Android for a very short time and I knew that something in the data was not right but I couldn't identify what. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, the mapping between JSON and data classes can be tricky sometimes :)